# Dealing with broken data, Paperclip, and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, amazon-s3, paperclip

I'm trying to run a simple `rake paperclip:refresh class=Photo`, but there is some sort of broken data, or a Photo that doesn't exist and it's causing this response :

```
...................................................rake aborted!
The specified key does not exist.
```

Assuming the error is caused by the photo not existing on the S3. What would be the best way to root out the culprit in a pile of 23,500 objects?

So far I've tried these commands...

```
Photo.all.select{|p|!p.photo.exists?}
```

But this has been running for 15 minutes..potentially having snagged, but nonethless keeping my laptop fan humming strongly.

I also tried..

```
Photo.all.select{|p|!p.photo}
```

But the same deal. Rooting through 23,500 objects on an S3 is no joke.

Any quicker, more cunning ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get a list of all objects in your S3 buckets using the aws-s3 or right-aws gem, whichever came with paperclip: http://amazon.rubyforge.org/

With that list you should be able to grab the path from each Photo and compare the arrays to see which objects no longer exist on s3. Something like:

```
Photo.all.map{|p| p.photo.path} - bucket.objects.map(&:key)
```

should get you the s3 objects which paperclip expects which don't exist.

Or if you'd prefer evil hackery, you could just wrap the blocks inside `Paperclip.each_instance_with_attachment` of https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/tasks/paperclip.rake with

```
begin

 `the code`

rescue 
 puts(instance.path, "doesn't exist") 
 next 
end
```

and copy the file to `lib/tasks/paperclip.rake`.

Comment: Great idea! I briefly thought of this path earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3 you should be able to do `Photo.all.where(:photo => nil)`.

Selecting all the records as you're doing in your example is a bad idea : as you've seen, it will take forever iterating over records that are of no interest to you...